# Printf raw data to a fixed length hex output

Tags: c, format, hex, printf

I have a struct, well pointer to a struct, and I wish to printf the first n bytes as a long hex number, or as a string of hex bytes.

Essentially I need the printf equivalent of gdb's examine memory command, x/nxb .

If possible I would like to still use printf as the program's logger function just variant of it. Even better if I can do so without looping through the data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just took Eric Postpischil's advice and cooked up the following :

```
struct mystruc
{
  int a;
  char b;
  float c;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  struct mystruc structVar={5,'a',3.9};
  struct mystruc* strucPtr=&structVar;
  unsigned char* charPtr=(unsigned char*)strucPtr;
  int i;
  printf("structure size : %zu bytes\n",sizeof(struct mystruc));
  for(i=0;i<sizeof(struct mystruc);i++)
      printf("%02x ",charPtr[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

It will print the bytes as fas as the structure stretches.

Update : Thanks for the insight Eric :)  I have updated the code.

Comment: Sizes should be printed with “%zu”. This is the format for the unsigned `size_t` type, which may differ from the signed `int` type that “%d” is for. And it may be preferable to print bytes with “%02x” rather than “%x”. The latter prints only one digit if the value is small enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Say you have pointer to struct in `pstruct`.

```
unsigned long long *aslong = (unsigned long long *)pstruct;
printf("%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x", 
       aslong[0],
       aslong[1],
       aslong[2],
       aslong[3],
       aslong[4],
       aslong[5],
       aslong[6],
       aslong[7],
);
```

As Eric points out, this might print the bytes out-of-order. So it's either this, or using `unsigned char *` and (having a `printf` with 64 arguments or using a loop).

Comment: This should use `unsigned char`. `char` may be signed, in which case the promotion to `int` that occurs when passing to printf will cause negative values to appear as 32-bit negative values. E.g., the byte 0xff will be printed as “ffffffff”. Additionally, “%02x” is a better format to use, since you likely want leading zeroes rather than spaces.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I need to print 64 bytes, rather than 3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: thanks for the comments. unsigned is indeed the way to go, and `0` as well.

Comment: @rhlee: you could have just done it 5 more times, but i think using `unsigned long long` should work - oh wait that's 8 bytes, not 64... you can write out 64 `unsigned long long`s in that case. or you can loop. but might be more efficient to have it unrolled as it is here

Comment: `unsigned char` is better; it will show the bytes in address order. Using wider integer types has endian problems; it may show the bytes out of order.