# Print raw data in hex from struct containing pointers

Tags: c, pointers, hex, printf

As a peculiar continuation of a question of printing raw hex data from a struct: [Printf raw data to a fixed length hex output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992677/printf-raw-data-to-a-fixed-length-hex-output)

I have a struct that contains pointers to other data. Is there any simple way to printf this struct *and* the contents of the pointers as raw hex values in one continuous stream? When printing the hex values of B below using:

```
// @note not actually valid code
struct B myStruct;
struct A myOtherStruct;
myStruct.c = &myOtherStruct;
unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)myStruct;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(struct B) + sizeof(struct A); i++) // 
  printf("%02x ", p[i]);
```

I naturally only get an address at `myStruct.c` (because that's what it is, I presume).

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  char b;
};
struct B
{
  int a;
  char b;
  void * c; // usually a struct A, ignore type-safety for simplicity 
};
```

I tried manually making room for data in `struct B` with `malloc` and copying `struct A` over, but didn't seem to do the trick. Trying this out of mostly curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are looping over `struct B` and printing `void * c`, you are printing the value of the pointer (i.e. the memory address).

Therefore, either you embed `struct A` directly in `struct B` (instead of a pointer); or the printing code is written so that it is aware of the pointer, dereferences it and prints that (you need to know how big the memory is there -- since you say `// usually a struct A`, let's assume the program knows; otherwise, you need to keep what is there; or at least its size).